extract frames from multiple videos using ffmpeg
i need to extract about 4 frames each second from various video clips and i tried this via cmd

forfiles /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -i "@FILE" -vf fps=4/1
frame_%05d.png

this frankenstein is the result of having no clue what to do and copy/pasta.
this will create up to 25 frames and constantly overwrite them too.
i do know how to run

ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vf fps=4/1 %d04.png

this works as intended, but i have to do this for each file :(
i hope someone can help me. thanks in advance!

See my profile. If you have troubles creating the simpliest loop possible, that has like 1000 duplicates here because of how counterintuitive batch is, it's perhaps time to switch to a more understandable scripting language.

What exactly is your intention save all frames from all mp4 files in one folder? Lets say first movie has 3000 frames -> 03000 when the extraction of the second movie starts it should continue on 03001?

guess i should just asked grok from the start...
so for everyone else who is trying to get x-amount of frames out of unlimited video clips try to use this:

forfiles /s /m *.mp4 /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @FILE -vf fps=4
@fname_frame_%05d.png"

it wont create a corresponding folder for each clip but just output every x-amount of frames (works for me)
thanks anyway.
